# How to show ole image of mdb in a form

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have an mdb database with some pictures. I would like to show these pictures on my form. I dragged the datagrid to my form but when I test it, I'm getting error. Here's a screenshot:

[screenshot http://img842.imageshack.us/img842/8487/60j9.png](http://img842.imageshack.us/img842/8487/60j9.png)

How can I fix this and show the pictures on my form?

Edit:

I have this code:

```
Private Sub SarkilarBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SarkilarBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
    Me.Validate()
    Me.SarkilarBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.ThmDataSet)

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'ThmDataSet.sarkilar' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.SarkilarTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ThmDataSet.sarkilar)

End Sub
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2012

Comment: fix the argument to `Image.FromStream` which is incorrect.  want more info? show the code that you are using.

Comment: where are you loading the image?

Comment: I loaded the image with ms access and I only have a datagrid on the form.

Comment: Why not use a builtin image control on your form ?